# Why was I able to execute a method without qualifying the object name?

Tags: vba

I was automating an Outlook email from excel today when I noticed I forgot a line but somehow it still worked and I didn't get a compile error.  Is there such as thing as a default library object?

```
Sub sendmail()

Dim olmsg As Outlook.MailItem

'This works
Set olmsg = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'What it should be
Set olmsg = Outlook.Application.CreateItem


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When working in Outlook, it automatically recognizes Outlook types.
Similar to how Excel will recognize keywords such as ActiveSheet and ActiveCell without first expressing Excel.Application.

It is good practice to use the longhand expression, incase you ever need to port a similar code to Excel for working in Outlook, and because VBA does not handle overflows well.